# Do people in Japan really shower all the time after a rainstorm, or is that just an anime thing?

Tags: tropes, recovery-of-an-mmo-junkie

I just watched the latest Net-juu no Susume and there's the stereotypical caught-in-the-rain scene, and then usually accompanying shower scene.  Since this anime makes a point to be more similar to the real world than others, it made me wonder if this sort of thing actually happens in Japan.  I recognized [the trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CaughtInTheRain) from anime, but in researching this question, it seems that it's also common in other mediums.

Is the rain that cold over there?  Do people usually take showers at other people's houses after a downpour takes them by surprise?

Comment: I often take showers after being caught by heavy rainfall. Nice way to warm up, and when rain dries in the hair, it will feel awkward. (note I am not from japan)

Comment: I would too, if I was at my house.  However, at a stranger's house or a friends house, that never comes to the table as an option.

Comment: Personally I would offer it to friends or family. To a stranger, probably not more than a towel to dry off with.

Comment: are you talking about ofuro

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of whether the rain was cold or not, taking a shower after a downpour has a health related reason. The rain is not a very clean source of water with the factories and other pollutants in the air. Taking shower was meant to wash away the dirts.

As to offering shower to non-household members, it is a show of hospitality. As Dimitri MX and you said in the comment, it would differ from one people to another. Some would offer shower, while others might offer just some towel.

As a comparison, in Indonesia (another Asian country), we were taught to have shower, or at least wash our head after we got wet by rainwater. The believe was that if you let it be, you will get headache after some time.